# Retry count in deferred.defer in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using GAE's '[deffered](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred?hl=en)' library (python), which automatically retries the task in the event an exception is raised.

Is there a way to know (within the task handler function) the number of times the task has been tried?

My end goal is to implement something like:

```
if num_tries >5:
  email_admins()
  raise deferred.PermanentTaskFailure
```

Initially I thought I could use 'TaskRetryOptions' to limit the number of tries, but I believe that doesnt provide a mechanism for my email_admins() call. Or does it?

[edit] of course I could read/write the number of tries to the DB or memcache, but I'd prefer to avoid that complexity. I'd prefer to get the details from the task / task queue if possible.

Comment: I would suggest using the accepted solution here -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36604616/specifying-retry-limit-for-tasks-queued-using-gae-deferred-library/36621588#36621588

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several headers will be set automatically with task
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push

> X-AppEngine-TaskRetryCount, the number of times this task has been
> retried; for the first attempt, this value is 0. This number includes
> attempts where the task failed due to a lack of available instances
> and never reached the execution phase.
>
> X-AppEngine-TaskExecutionCount, the number of times this task has previously failed during the execution phase. This number does not include failures due to a lack of available instances.

## EDIT 1

These values can access:

```
num_tries  = self.request.headers.get('X-AppEngine-TaskRetryCount')
```

## EDIT 2

http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.get_request

for defered try:

```
request = webapp2.get_request()
```

Comment: Yes, but is there an easy way to get at these when using `deferred`?

Comment: is self.request valid in the context of deferred?

Comment: but a task handler is not executing in the context of a webapp(2) request. I'll give it a try anyway..

Comment: I tested it, and webapp2.get_request().headers.get('X-AppEngine-TaskRetryCount') does indeed work - thanks!

Comment: I would suggest using the accepted solution here -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36604616/specifying-retry-limit-for-tasks-queued-using-gae-deferred-library/36621588#36621588